# runas administrator and runas user with administrative privileges

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am trying to run the chkdsk.exe but i noticed it only works when i right-click and select runas administrator anything other than this will only flash on the screen and disappear immediatley. I also tried using a batch file but this is what i get after running it:

```
    Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges.
You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is wat confuses me because my user account is an admin account **(my laptop)** but wen i right-click and choose `runas admin` the utility works fine .
so i want to know the difference between this two admin accounts

Comment: It's because you've got UAC enabled.  [Put this](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin) in your script and your script will prompt for elevation before running.  Either that or turn off UAC.

Comment: To start an administrative command-line window, press the Start button (or the Windows key), type cmd, and press CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER.  Or on Windows 8 or later, you can use the keyboard shortcut: Windows-X A.  You can run chkdsk, or a batch file that calls chkdsk, from that window.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two things. Rightclicking a file and selecting "run as administrator" means that you are running the application with **your account** but with elevated rights (using your "admin power"). Any user who has admin rights can do this. This does not mean that you are running the application under the user called Administrator.

On the other hand, when you just double-click a file it is run under your user name but without elevated rights.

It's all about the stupid Windows UCA. You can avoid this problem by deactivating it.

Comment: Typo - UCA, not UAC.  And turning it off is *not* the right solution.